# BeginRequest is called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have created an `HttpModule`:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class TestModule : IHttpModule
{
    public TestModule() {  }

    public String ModuleName { get { return "TestModule"; } }

    public void Dispose() {  }

    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        app.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.DoBeginRequest));
    }

    private void DoBeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        context.Response.Write("<pre>Request URL: " + context.Request.FilePath + "</pre>");
        context.Response.Flush();            
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(context.Request.ToString());
    }
}
```

Which is loaded like so:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="TestModule" type="TestModule"/>
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

When i call this from a web browser, or from `curl`, i get two log lines in the Output tab, and i see the following response:

```
<pre>Request URL: /example</pre><pre>Request URL: /example</pre>
```

Which indicates that it is the same Context each time.  **Why is this happening?**  There are a lot of fields in the `Request` object, but i've not been able to spot any difference between them in the two calls.  Is there some property i should be checking that gives a "stage" that i should only be responding to one of?

I have found a few related questions here on the site, but most of them seem to lean toward it being the web browser looking for another resource, like `favicon.ico`, and that is not the case here.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) seems a bit light on details for `BeginRequest`, so i've not found a lot of help there so far.

I may be missing something obvious, this is my first encounter with .NET/IIS etc, i am a Java dev usually.

**Update**:

I've dumped all the public properties of `Request` and this is the difference between the two:

```
Headers == Accept=*%2f*&Host=localhost%3a2017&User-Agent=curl%2f7.35.0
Headers == Content-Length=0&Accept=*%2f*&Host=localhost%3a2017&User-Agent=curl%2f7.35.0
```

Specifically, the `Content-Length` header is getting set on the second call.  This wasn't present in the request `curl` made:

```
> GET /example HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:2017
> Accept: */*
```

Is this IIS trying to be helpful?  After it's handled the whole request it knows how long the body is (0) and calls it again with that set?

Comment: The problem can hide in a lot of places...
I suggest to set a breakpoint where Response value is append with the string and see when it will be triggered for the 2-nd time.
Check call stack to see who initiated 2-nd call.

Comment: Is there a way to put IISExpress into some kind of a debug mode?  All i see in the call stack is `DoBeginRequest` preceeded by `[External code]`

Comment: Very interesting IIS behavior...you may find this article useful, but solution from it won't work in our case: http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after much frustration i discovered that specific URLs did *not* suffer from this behaviour.  URLs with an "extension" don't do it:

```
curl http://localhost:2017/test
 > BeginRequest
 > BeginRequest 

curl http://localhost:2017/test.abc
 > BeginRequest

curl http://localhost:2017/.a
 > BeginRequest
```

Through some more digging online i've found references to a Handler called `ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0` which is loaded by the main config file `applicationhost.config`.  I don't really know what this is doing, nor why it causes requests to be duplicated, but explicitly removing it in my own `web.config` has solved the problem:

```
   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      </handlers>
      <modules>
        <add name="TestModule" type="TestModule"/>
      </modules>
    </system.webServer>
```

I must admit that i am a bit afraid of what other similar pitfalls i might encounter later on - `applicationhost.config` loads a *lot* of other handlers and modules, any of which might be messing with stuff like this before my module is able to get at it.  But that's a problem for another day...

Comment: Great observation and nice solution. I read almost 15 questions in SO with neither of them offering a correct explanation or even a solution to the issue. I would post this observation under every single of them to get credit.

Comment: However I had to remove 3 of them (windows 10/server 2019), `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit`, 
`ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit` and
`ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0`. Also redirect from folder to folder default document is still happening which I still need to happen

Answer (score 2):

(Note: this solution may not be appropriate in every application)

Just call CompleteRequest() at the end of your event handler (be it BeginRequest, PostAuthorizeRequest, or something else).

This call finishes request processing and prevents other handlers from working, but if you have already handled it, most likely, you don't expect post-processing to take place, so no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Using LogRequest event listener instead of BeginRequest should work for your purpose:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication app)
{
    app.LogRequest += DoBeginRequest; // TODO: Rename your function
}
```

Yes, I see your behavior on very clean ASP.NET Web Application.
And it is not related to `favicon.ico` additional request.
It may relate to multiple application instances, that IIS may create in application pool. And multiple instances of your module with multiple subscriptions to same event. It somewhere here...but I cannot prove none of these theories in my code for now.

Comment: Using `LogRequest` does seem to behave correctly, but it doesn't feel "right" to be using it to do actual work (in this case i am going to use it to effectively proxy to another process via some IPC mechanism).  I am also not feeling confident that i understand it well enough to be able to rely on `LogRequest` working either!

Comment: Upon further investigation, `LogRequest` is also being called twice, however only one of the `Response` streams ever gets back to the client.  Is IIS always this difficult?  I feel like this is such a simple "Hello World" app, yet something is still very wrong, and i must be missing something obvious.